# modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found in directory

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-20.04, fuse

I am trying to mount a remote dir onto my local machine using `sshfs`.
My local is running Ubuntu 20.04. When I try:

```
sudo modprobe fuse
```

I get:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.162-1-pve
```

Fuse (2.9.9-3) is installed on my local machine. The `/lib` path does not hold a `modules/` directory.

How can I make `modprobe` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote machine is a Linux container. That explains why the `modprobe` command is not working.